# Sprite nav menu rendering incorrectly in IE when the page is reloaded

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I am having an issue with my site. I have a nav vertical menu that works well in all browsers. I have it set so that when you hover over the image, it shifts position to display the on hover image (like a sprite). However, in IE9 and IE9 in compatibility mode, when I click on one of the links and navigate away from the page and then click back to return to the page, IE puts the on hover image sprite of the last item in the menu as the first image in the menu. It is only when you click the page that this corrects itself. Below is the css.

```
    #nav{
clear:both;
float:left;
width:200px;
margin-right:20px;  
}

    /*.menu li{
height:28px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .menu a:link{
position:relative;
top:0;
    }
    .menu a:hover{
    top: -28px; 
    }*/

   .menu {
   position:relative;

    margin-left:-10px;
    }
    .menu li{
    /*height:30px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:10px;*/
    margin:10px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    top:0;
    }

   .menu li a{
    /*height:60px;*/
    display:block;
    }
   .btnPromodirect a{
     height:28px;
     width:200px;
     background:url('../links/promodirect_button.jpg') 200px 0;
    }
   .btnPromotionmag a{
    height:28px;
    width:200px;
    background:url('../links/promotionmagazine_button.jpg') 200px 0;
     }

    .btnPromota a{
     height:28px;
     width:200px;
      background:url('../links/promota_button.jpg') 200px 0;
     }
   .btnPpib a{
     height:28px;
     width:200px;
     background:url('../links/ppib_buton.jpg') 200px 0;
     }


   .btnPromodirect, .btnPromotionmag, .btnPromota, .btnPpib{
     border: none !important;
     outline: none !important;
    }
   .btnPromodirect a:hover, a:active{

     background:url('../links/promodirect_button.jpg') 0 -28px;
     }

    .btnPromotionmag a:hover, a:active{
     background:url('../links/promotionmagazine_button.jpg') 0 -28px;
    }

    .btnPromota a:hover, a:active{
     background:url('../links/promota_button.jpg') 0 -28px;
    }

    .btnPpib  a:hover, a:active{
    background:url('../links/ppib_buton.jpg') 0 -28px;
     }
```

below is the html

```
    <div id="nav">

     <ul class="menu">

     <li class="btnPromodirect"><a href="http://www.promodirect.com.au"></a></li>
     <li class="btnPromotionmag"><a href="http://www.promotionmagazine.com.au">       </a></li>
     <li class="btnPromota"><a href="http://www.promota.com.au"></a></li>
     <li class="btnPpib"><a href="http://www.ppib.com.au"></a></li>

     </ul>
     </div>

     </div>
```

I am fairly new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the css for btnPromodirect, btnPromotionmag ... etc. and also one extra div is closing ... Let us know, it helps ...

Comment: thanks for this.  the css for btnPromodirect etc is the 5 buttons on the menu.  when you click on any item in the menu it goes to the appropriate link.  then when you come back to the site, it is displaying the bottom sprite for whenever item was clicked.  no idea why this is happening.  can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Whereever you are using background like..

```
background:url('../links/promodirect_button.jpg') 200px 0;
```

Add **no-repeat** as well...

```
background:url('../links/promodirect_button.jpg') 200px 0 no-repeat;
```

Try this and let me know if it helps ...

Comment: hi there, thanks for your advice.  unfortunately this did not work.  it's only in IE i have this problem.  in chrome, firefox etc everything works fine.  please let me know if you have any other suggestions.  i really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share and dummy link or put it in jsfiddle so that I can look into it ...

Comment: thanks am trying to work out how to do this.  will post again soon.

Comment: am trying to set this up in jsfiddle.  you can't see the problem though as i can't work out how to add the links (jpeg buttons).  do you know how i can do this?